# Can <a href> accept multiple parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've 5 different static pages: `index.html` `syllabus-link.html` `advanced-linux.html` `contact.html` `gallery.html`.

The functionality is quite simple - User clicks on one of the syllabus type and the user is presented with a `word file' having 2 options:

**1) Download

2) View its contents.**

> The syllabus menu-header is not clickable, but when the user hovers on it, it would list the syllabus types in its dropdown-menu.

Let's say, I'm on `index.html` page and being there, I decided to click on "Linux" option from the dropdown-menu of syllabus page. The Linux `word file` gets displayed on the screen with options for the user to either view it's contents or download the word file(**based on jQuery condition written in syllabus page**).  Now that I've landed on the syllabus page and this time when I try clicking on other options viz.., "Hadoop" or "CCNA",  nothing shows up. But had I tried clicking either of "Hadoop" or "CCNA" option being on `index.html` page, it displays the correct "word file".

```
From external page ==> click works

Being on syllabus page ==> click doesn't work
```

> Functionality is similar to what is shown ==>> `https://www.atcs.com/` **ABOUT US**
> section

I understand that if I write `<a href="#">`in syllabus page, then the current issue can be fixed, but I would lose the current working functionality. How do I achieve both?

**Any help would be highly appreciated !!!**

[image: Menu header]

**index.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="headerlogo four columns">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html">
            <h4>Linux classes</h4>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="headermenu eight columns noleftmarg">
        <nav id="nav-wrap">
            <ul id="main-menu" class="nav-bar sf-menu">
                <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a>Syllabus</a>
                    <ul class="syllabus-options">
                        <li><a href="syllabus-link.html#linuxSyllabus"><strong>Linux</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="syllabus-link.html#hadoopSyllabus"><strong>Hadoop</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="syllabus-link.html#ccnaSyllabus"><strong>CCNA</strong></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="advanced-linux.html">Advanced Linux</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Personal Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

**syllabus-link.html**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="headerlogo four columns">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">
                <h4>Linux classes</h4>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="headermenu eight columns noleftmarg">
            <nav id="nav-wrap">
            <ul id="main-menu" class="nav-bar sf-menu">
                <li class="current">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a>Syllabus</a>
                    <ul class="syllabus-options">
                        <li><a href="#linuxSyllabus"  id="linux"><strong>Linux</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#hadoopSyllabus" id="hadoop"><strong>Hadoop</strong></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#ccnaSyllabus"   id="ccna"><strong>CCNA</strong></a></li>                  
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="advanced-linux.html">Advanced Linux</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="gallery.html">Personal Gallery</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>


<div id="linuxSyllabus" style="text-align: center;">  
        <!-- GOOGLE MAP IFRAME -->
        <font color="red"><h5>
                <b>Click on the word icon to <font color="blue"><blink>View
                        </blink></font> the complete Linux syllabus:
                </b>
            </h5></font>

        <p align="center">
            <a href="syllabus.htm" view> <img border="0"
                src="images/icon_word.png" alt="syllabus" width="75" height="75">
            </a>
        </p>
        <br> <font color="red" size="20px"><b> OR </b></font><br> <font
            color="red"><h5>
                <b>Click on the word icon to <font color="blue"><blink>Download
                        </blink></font> the complete Linux syllabus:
                </b>
            </h5></font>

        <p align="center">
            <a href="documents/0- Linux-Syllabus-Jan-2015.rtf" download> <img
                border="0" src="images/icon_word.png" alt="syllabus" width="75"
                height="75">
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="hadoopSyllabus" style="text-align: center;">
        <!-- GOOGLE MAP IFRAME -->
        <font color="red"><h5>
                <b>Click on the word icon to <font color="blue"><blink>View
                        </blink></font> the complete Hadoop syllabus:
                </b>
            </h5></font>

        <p align="center">
            <a href="syllabus.htm" view> <img border="0"
                src="images/icon_word.png" alt="syllabus" width="75" height="75">
            </a>
        </p>
        <br> <font color="red" size="20px"><b> OR </b></font><br> <font
            color="red"><h5>
                <b>Click on the word icon to <font color="blue"><blink>Download
                        </blink></font> the complete Hadoop syllabus:
                </b>
            </h5></font>

        <p align="center">
            <a href="documents/0- Linux-Syllabus-Jan-2015.rtf" download> <img
                border="0" src="images/icon_word.png" alt="syllabus" width="75"
                height="75">
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div id="ccnaSyllabus" style="text-align: center;"> 
            
        <font color="red"><h5>
                <b>Click on the PDF icon to <font color="blue"><blink>View
                        </blink></font>the complete CCNA syllabus:<br><br>  
                    
                    <a href="documents/2- CCNA-Syllabus.pdf" target="_blank">
                    <img border="0" src="images/icon_pdf.jpg" alt="syllabus" width="75" height="75">
                    </a>        
                </b>
            </h5></font>
        
        <br> <font color="red" size="20px"><b> OR </b></font><br> <font
            color="red"><h5>
                <b>Click on the PDF icon to <font color="blue"><blink>Download
                        </blink></font> the complete CCNA syllabus:
                </b>
            </h5></font>

        <p align="center">
            <a href="documents/2- CCNA-Syllabus.pdf" download> <img
                border="0" src="images/icon_pdf.jpg" alt="syllabus" width="75"
                height="75">
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

**JS file within syllabus-link.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var anc = window.location.href.split('#')[1];
        var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");

        if (document.getElementById(anc) == linuxSyllabus) {
            $("#hadoopSyllabus").hide();
            $("#ccnaSyllabus").hide();
            $("#linuxSyllabus").show();

        } else if (document.getElementById(anc) == hadoopSyllabus) {
            $("#linuxSyllabus").hide();
            $("#ccnaSyllabus").hide();
            $("#hadoopSyllabus").show();

        } else if (document.getElementById(anc) == ccnaSyllabus) {
            $("#linuxSyllabus").hide();
            $("#hadoopSyllabus").hide();
            $("#ccnaSyllabus").show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The URL you provided does not appear to show anything like what you are asking for and there is no "About Us" page that I can gather.  I may be alone but I am not going to hunt for it.  Consider clarifying your question with Images or other means.

Comment: @mindfreak if you want help, you need to tell the people willing to help you what you are trying to achieve. Replying to their answers with, "it can be inferred from X" is not helpful. Please explain what YOU are trying to to achieve.

Comment: @Steve have edited the question, please have a look.

Comment: @Tyler please have a look at the edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for making it more clear on what you are trying to accomplish, the html and javascript you added helps significantly. The issue you are seeing is the javascript is only being run once on page load. I would recommend wrapping that up in a function, that way you can call it on page load, as you are doing now, as well as every time one of those links is clicked.

**js file within syllabus**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // this will get called when you want to swap the visible div
        function updateVisibleDiv(viewName) {
            // we are going to pass in a string as viewName, we want to check it against a string
            // also, I added show for each syllabus, since we will be calling this to change
            // which syllabus is visible, we have to show the one they select
            if (viewName == 'linuxSyllabus') {
                $("#hadoopSyllabus").hide();
                $("#ccnaSyllabus").hide();
                $("#linuxSyllabus").show();
            } else if (viewName == 'hadoopSyllabus') {
                $("#linuxSyllabus").hide();
                $("#ccnaSyllabus").hide();
                $("#hadoopSyllabus").show();
            } else if (viewName == 'ccnaSyllabus') {
                $("#linuxSyllabus").hide();
                $("#hadoopSyllabus").hide();
                $("#ccnaSyllabus").show();
            }
        }

        // this will get run on page load - I like wrapping it in a function to make
        // it more clear what we are doing on page initialization
        function init() {
            var syllabus = window.location.href.split('#')[1];
            // syllabus should equal one of ['linuxSyllabus', 'hadoopSyllabus', 'ccnaSyllabus']
            // we pass it in to our function, and it loads the correct screen
            // up to this point, the page will work the same as it always has, this is just a refactor
            updateVisibleDiv(syllabus);
        }

        // this will be the new functionality that updates which syllabus is visible
        // this will be called when a link is clicked
        function updateView() {
            // get the value in your href from the clicked link
            var syllabus = this.getAttribute('href').split('#')[1];
            // now we will just update the visible div
            updateVisibleDiv(syllabus);
        }

        // we are going to attach a click event to those three links
        // this is selecting all 3 links by their id, and adding an on click event handler
        $('#linux, #hadoop, #ccna').on('click', updateView);

        // call the init function to initialize the page
        init();
    });
</script>
```

Disclaimer: I wasn't able to test this myself, let me know if you have any issues and I can try to help you work through them.

Answer (score 0):

One big problem is that your conditionals within the `if` and `else if` statements should be using strings.

eg. `if (document.getElementById(anc) == 'linuxSyllabus')`

Secondly, you are using selectors within each conditional, and as far as I can tell those id's do not exist in the html. Your id's are `linux`, `hadoop`, and `ccna`.

You will want to select those as `$('linux')` OR by the href like this:
`$("a[href='#linuxSyllabus'")`

I'm somewhat unsure of the problem you are actually looking to solve, but those are some code issues that jump out at me.  Also try checking the console in your browser and you'll surely see some errors.

Comment: The functionality that I wish to achieve can be inferred from `https://www.atcs.com/` ABOUT US section.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it is what you looking for or not. I just give a solution whatever I can understand from your description.

You can use a common class for every syllabus container in syllabus like `.syllabusContainer` and change js like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var anc = window.location.href.split('#')[1];
    var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");
    $(".syllabusContainer").hide();
    $("#"+anc).show();
  });
</script>
```

in syllabus page use same menu link as index.html

Comment: The functionality that I wish to achieve can be inferred from https://www.atcs.com/ ABOUT US section.

Comment: the answer doesn't help.